# Which key bindings to use for switchable primary and secondary attacks?

Tags: input, keyboard

I am making a game in which the player can have a primary and secondary weapon (like an ability). These are my current planned key bindings:

```
 Action | Effect
-----------------
 Click  | Shoot primary weapon
 WASD   | Move
 Space  | Use ability (secondary weapon)
 Q      | Previous primary weapon
 E      | Next primary weapon
 ???    | Previous/Next ability (secondary weapon)
```

I am trying to think of a way to switch the secondary weapon. Here are some options I have thought of and why I have rejected them:

- scroll wheel

  - some mice don't have scroll wheels
- <kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>F</kbd>

  - awkward, also primary weapon switch is horizontal and this is vertical
- <kbd>shift</kbd> / ???

  - cannot think of another key

So, what is a good key binding for switching a secondary attack?

Comment: Scroll wheel or (Shift|Alt|Ctrl)+Q/(Shift|Alt|Ctrl)+E or TAB (just cycle to next if you don't have too many abilities) or Forward/Back buttons on mouse (not universal) or Right click with on screen "command rose"

Comment: @Byte56 Scroll wheel explained in question, the modifiers might work, tab is only one key and there might be many abilities, forward/back buttons are very rare, right click not usable because then you can't shoot simultaneously.

Comment: @Byte56 space is also just one key. I don't want to rely on scroll wheels because laptops and stuff.

Comment: Space/Tab to cycle. Also, if someone is playing this on a laptop, they're likely using an external mouse.

Comment: @Byte56 That might work! (but probably space/shift instead because when fingers are on WASD shift is more accessible.)

Comment: @Byte56 If you post all those options as an answer I will accept it; it worked for me

Comment: Usually will be X or TAB

Comment: Why not let the user decide? Everyone has their own preference.

Comment: @Hydrocity Yes, but the problem is: decide between what? (which is now solved with Byte56's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Scroll wheel
- (Shift|Alt|Ctrl)+Q/(Shift|Alt|Ctrl)+E
- TAB (just cycle to next if you don't have too many abilities)
- Forward/Back buttons on mouse (not universal)
- Right click with on screen "command rose"
- Space/Tab to cycle
- TAB to switch modes, Q/E switches weapons in mode 0, Q/E switches abilities in mode 1
- Shift/Tab to cycle